# Online store buyer trying to scam

Tags: scams, fraud

I posted an item on OLX and somebody inquired for it. I thought it would be a good deal but when he sent the money, the bank (It's fake) asks for a scanned shipment receipt so that they'll transfer it to my account.

My question is, is it possible to them to hack my card with the specific info below?

- Bank Name
- Account Number
- ACC Holders Name
- SWIFT CODE
- Email address

Comment: Why would you send *any* info if you know it's a scam?

Comment: I never thought it is. Not until he said that I have to send a shipment receipt to receive the cash from the bank.

Comment: If you have sent this information to the scammer, you should call your bank and let them know. If you haven't sent them any info, just cut off contact. If they sent you a payment, let your bank know that you've come to believe it's fraudulent.

Comment: What country are you in? And what country is the buyer from? There is no need for SWIFT CODE or Email address

Comment: I don't know what a swift code is, so I don't know how damaging that might be.  The rest is fairly harmless, I think.  (Email is not needed to transfer money, but I don't think it would help them hack you either - other than giving them another vector to strike at.)  In any case, telling your bank what's happening can only help to prevent problems.  Updating your passwords (especially bank/email related passwords) to something secure is probably also wise.